# Intersection of N lists, or of an N-d array

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I often find myself having to do `np.intersect1d()` multiple times because I need to find the intersection of a number of list like or array like things. So I ended up creating a function for it. Though, if possible I'd like to simplify / and or speed up the code for when the input becomes rather large.

```
def overlap(splits):
    uniques = {item: 0 for item in list(set([i for x in splits for i in x]))}
    for idx in range(len(splits)):
        for val in list(set(splits[idx])):
            if val in uniques.keys():
                uniques[val] += 1
    intersection = np.array([x for x in uniques.keys() if uniques[x] == len(splits)])
    return intersection
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can loop through a set, there is no need to wrap them in lists.
2. You can loop through `splits`, using `for i in range(len(splits)): splits[i]` is just long winded.
   Just use `for spilt in splits:`.
3. When checking if a key is in a dictionary, don't compare to it's `.keys()`, just do `'a' in dict`.
4. You should notice that you're forcing the dictionary to be pre-populated, alternately you could use `collections.defaultdict`.
5. After changing the code to use a `defaultdict` you should be able to notice that all you're doing is counting this:

   ```
   (item for split in splits for item in set(split))
   ```

   And so you could use `collections.Counter` instead.
6. In your final loop you use `.keys()` and then use `uniques[x]`. Instead you should use `.items()`, with tuple unpacking.
7. Finally you should aim at improving the readability, so I generate all the items on one line. And build the np array on another.

This can result in:

```
from collections import Counter

def overlap(splits):
    items = (item for split in splits for item in set(split))
    return np.array([k for k, v in Counter(items).items() if v == len(splits)])
```

---

However this does the same as [`np.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) with two arrays as input. The docs also say, that if you wish to intersect more than two arrays you can use:

> ```
> >>> from functools import reduce
> >>> reduce(np.intersect1d, ([1, 3, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 1], [6, 3, 4, 2]))
> array([3])
> ```

Comment: so i guess im not understanding `np.intersect1d()` correctly as I thought it wouldn't work if for example I want the intersection of 5 or 6 lists all at once ?

Comment: @atomsmasher I can't read it's docs, I'm getting a server timeout error. So I assumed it's `intersect1d(*arrays)`. If this is not correct I will remove the last part.

Comment: it seems the way to get intersection of N arrays using `np.intersect1d()` is `np.intersect1d([many, arrays, here], [one array left out])`

Comment: `np.intersect1d` passes each of the 2 inputs through `np.unique`.  I don't think it will work with lists of lists.  It concatenates these, sorts the result and returns the duplicates.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, I no-longer getting a server timeout for `np.intersect1d`. I'll change it to what they say you could do.

Answer (score 1):

This `set` based solution tests faster, at least for a small test case:

```
def foo(ll):
    ls=[set(l) for l in ll]
    fst=ls[0]
    for l in ls[1:]:
        fst.intersection_update(l)
    return fst
```

`intersect1d` suggests you can apply it to multiple list with `reduce`:

```
functools.reduce(np.intersect1d, ll)   # py3 reduce
```

Or using the `set` approach:

```
functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x.intersection(set(y)), ll[1:], set(ll[0]))
```

I tested these with

```
ll = [[1,2,5,8,1],[0,2,4,3,5,6],[0,1,0,1,3,6,2]]
```

==============

A single step function along the lines of `intersect1d` would do:

```
 N = len(args)
 ll = [np.unique(l) for l in args]
 A = np.concatenate(ll)
 A = np.sort(A)
 <find all entries that occur exactly N times>

In [1643]: ll=[[1,2,5,8,1],[0,2,4,3,5,6],[0,1,0,1,3,6,2]]
In [1644]: l1=[np.unique(l) for l in ll]
In [1645]: l1=np.concatenate(l1)
In [1646]: l1=np.sort(l1)
In [1647]: l1
Out[1647]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8])
In [1648]: c=Counter(l1)
In [1649]: c
Out[1649]: Counter({0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 8: 1})
In [1650]: [k for k,v in c.items() if v==3]
Out[1650]: [2]
```